# Changing desktop environment from Gnome to KDE in CentOS

Tags: gnome, kde, centos-5, desktop-environments

I have installed my CentOS machine with the GNOME desktop environment. I would like to change it to KDE. I am already in the process of downloading and installing KDE packages, will that conflict with GNOME?

1. Can I keep both desktop environments and choose what I want to use?
2. How can I remove the GNOME packages and not disturb my current configuration in anyway?

I am a new user and hence would like to encounter as little complications as possible, please advise.

Comment: yum install kde ?

Comment: @Sathya - :) I have already installed KDE now, said that in the post too.. more interested in removing the GNOME environment without causing any conflicts or problems.

Comment: OK- you can keep both DE if you want. To remove Gnome it should be `yum groupremove "GNOME"`. Since you have KDE Installed, it shouldn't be a problem  - but I've not done this hence I'm leaving as a comment rather than a definitive answer :) @rzlines

Comment: @Sathya - Wondering if I should go ahead and do that? or wait till I get a definitive reply? I'm new to this and I have done a lot of modifications to my setup.

Comment: I'd wait for someone like @Gilles or @Ignacio to reply :) both are quite experienced in this regard :)

Answer (score 1):

KDE (K Desktop Environment) is an alternative GUI for Gnome, some people prefer KDE over Gnome for some reason since they are basically similar. To install KDE on Centos, use this command on your system terminal:

```
# yum groupinstall "KDE desktop"
```

From http://namhuy.net/475/how-to-install-gui-to-centos-minimal.html